# AWS Transcribe javascript API UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'OutputBucketName' found in params

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js, amazon-transcribe

I am calling the AWS Transcribe service from a Lambda

Lambda code:

```
  module.exports.createTranscribeJob = (event, context, callback) => {
  const region = event.Records[0].awsRegion;
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
  const transcribeservice = new AWS.TranscribeService({apiVersion: '2017-10-26'});

  // Set the  transcribeservice startTranscriptionJob params
  const params = {
    LanguageCode: 'en-US',
    Media: {
      MediaFileUri: `https://s3-${region}.amazonaws.com/${bucket}/${key}`
    },
    MediaFormat: 'mp3',
    TranscriptionJobName: key,
    MediaSampleRateHertz: 0,
    OutputBucketName: bucket
  };

  // call startTranscriptionJob with the params
  transcribeservice.startTranscriptionJob(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

  callback(null);
};
```

I set the version of the API I want to use `new AWS.TranscribeService({apiVersion: '2017-10-26'})`

When I call `transcribeservice.startTranscriptionJob` the job fails with this error:

```
{ UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'OutputBucketName' found in params
at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:125:42)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:95:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:85:9
at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:320:7)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:338:9
message: 'Unexpected key \'OutputBucketName\' found in params',
code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
time: 2018-07-19T12:50:58.278Z }
```

If I remove `OutputBucketName: bucket` it works, so I know its not a permissions issue

Looking at the Source code for AWS Javascript sdk `OutputBucketName` is defined as a member of `StartTranscriptionJobRequest`
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/75978fcfe4186d5a310e9b5c6d6328e90997edf0/apis/transcribe-2017-10-26.normal.json#L491

My only guess is lambda is not using the correct SDK even though I state the API version.

Any help is appreciated, please let me know if I have an error on my side.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is AWS Lambda does not use the latest JS SDK

The solution is to include the latest JS SDK in your own node_module folder

`npm install aws-sdk`

Then your lambda code will use the latest version of the SDK

Answer (score 1):

Thanks John !!. This solution worked, If you where previously editing directly in the web UI, you will loose the ability to edit the code inline.

[image: Export Function]

Then once you download, unzip and run the command posted by John.

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

Finally, zip it back up, make sure your zip includes the node_modules directory as well as the .js files you originally downloaded